# Filtering Records For Logged in User Only?

Tags: php, sql

I use the following query to display records by joining form data with image data.

```
SELECT * FROM soccer JOIN soccerimages ON soccer.id = soccerimages.id ORDER BY soccer.id
```

This displays all records, form data with one image, but how do I only display the record for the logged in user? I need to make this private to avoid copyright issues, if users upload images from websites for example. The logged in user is stored in a session variable

```
$user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
```

I have tired

```
SELECT * FROM tcgsoccer JOIN tcgsoccerimages ON tcgsoccer.id = tcgsoccerimages.id ORDER BY tcgsoccer.id `WHERE '$user'='$user'`
```

But I get syntax errors. I don't understand how to structure the query? I am testing it in phpmyadmin so have removed the ;

Comment: Remove the quotes for the first ($user) `WHERE '$user'='$user'` so `WHERE user='$user'` assuming `user` is your column name.

Comment: No $user is the session variable. I've joined tables on their column ids.

Comment: create a stored procedure that accepts @user as a variable, call the stored procedure from your php code passing in $user as a parameter.

Comment: The syntax is `WHERE column = 'something'`, `$user` is not a column, it's a variable and column should not be wrapped in quotes. Here => http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm - Adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` would have signaled the error.

Comment: I am using error reporting error_reporting(E_ERROR); I don't know how to structure the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM tcgsoccer 
    JOIN tcgsoccerimages ON tcgsoccer.id = tcgsoccerimages.id 
        ORDER BY tcgsoccer.id 
WHERE user = '" . $user ."'";
```

Comment: That gives "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user = ''' at line 2". I removed the spaces as well but it gave the same error.